# Android Service do not working

Tags: android

My app follow next Scenarios...

`1.[Main Activity]`

- thread repeat sleep(5000)
- if thread is sleep(), startService()

`2.[Service.class] sendBroadcast()`

`3.[Main Activity - BroadcastReceiver] Toast()`

---

thread working clean, but service don't be called.

I register  in Manifest.xml

And I create BroadcastReceiver dynamic.

---

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".Service"
             android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Runnable {
Thread mThread;
Boolean mSleep = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("Activity", "onCreate()");
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("Activity", "onStart()");

    mThread = new Thread(this);
    mThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d("Thread", "run()");

    while(true) {
        try {
            mThread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //empty
        }
        Log.d("Thread", "sleep");
        mSleep = true;
        Log.d("Thread1", mSleep.toString());
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        context.startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service.class));

        mSleep = false;
        Log.d("Thread2", mSleep.toString());
    }
}   

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("Activity", "onResume()");

    Log.d("Is it main thread?", mThread.currentThread().getName());

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    //No Action
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Activity", "onPause()");

    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}

BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "sleep sleep sleep", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
}
```

Service.class

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Service", "onCreate()");

        Intent intent = new Intent();       
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Service", "onBind()");
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: What problem yoy are facing? Any error if yes logcat please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the package you imported, Service here is not android.app.Service

```
context.startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service.class));
```

Comment: My java class names are "MainActivity", "Service".

Comment: I didn't input 'android.app.Service' in there.

Comment: My code didn't have any error, but it'll may run problem.
Thanks!